# How to Rewrite Rule for folder permission error?

Tags: linux, apache, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I have assets[/admin/assets] directory which I restricted access from browser.
So whenever user requested on [/admin/assets] , I want to rewrite rule to [admin/index.html].

I tried with below setting , but this doesn't rewrite to expected path but show permission access error with 403.

```
RewriteRule /assets /index.html [L]
```

**I have one solution for that by handling ErrorDocument. But I don't prefer it that way, I want to handle by RewriteRule .**

Comment: "which I restricted access from browser." - How have you restricted access to this directory? Where is this `.htaccess` file located? (Any other `.htaccess` files?)

Comment: @MrWhite I set by Directory module with `Require All Denied`

Comment: And where are the `.htaccess` file(s) in which you have placed these directives?

Comment: I dont have .htaccess file . I use only httpd.conf

Comment: So, where were you trying to put the mod_rewrite directive(s)?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using the mod_rewrite module in Apache web server. You can add the following code in your .htaccess file or server configuration file to rewrite the URL:

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /assets
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ /admin/index.html [L]

The RewriteEngine directive turns on the rewriting engine.

The RewriteCond directive specifies a condition that must be met before the RewriteRule is applied. In this case, the condition checks if the requested URL starts with "/assets".

The RewriteRule directive specifies the actual URL rewriting. The pattern "^assets/(.)$" matches any URL that starts with "/assets/", and captures the rest of the URL into a group (.). The URL is then rewritten to "/admin/index.html". The [L] flag specifies that this is the last rule to be applied, so no further rewriting should take place.

Comment: It is not working either..

Comment: This looks like ChatGPT output? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned

Comment: There are many inconsistencies here... The `RewriteCond` directive isn't doing anything. "and captures the rest of the URL into a group" - why? It's not being used. "in your .htaccess file or server configuration" - The rule wouldn't match if it was directly in the "server config".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> I set by Directory module with `Require All Denied`

You can't block access *and* rewrite the request. The `<Directory>` container will take priority. (But there's no point blocking the request when you want to rewrite it. You are essentially blocking it by rewriting.)

Remove the `<Directory>` block and directly inside the `<VirtualHost>` container (outside of any `<Directory>` section) use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/admin/assets($|/) /admin/index.html [L]
```

Any requests to `/admin/assets` or `/admin/assets/<anything>` are internally rewritten to `/admin/index.html`.